# AC_SUBST does not expand variable

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, m4

In an Autotools project I am trying to generate parts of my .conf file. The program needs to read from `$(pkgdatadir)`, but I know that that variable is only set in `Makefile.in`, so I instead substituted `datadir` and `PACKAGE`.

configure.ac:

```
    AC_PREREQ([2.69])
    AC_INIT([foo], [1.0.0], [me@foo.com])
    AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([foo.c])
    AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
    AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
    AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])

    AC_SUBST(datadir)
    AC_SUBST(PACKAGE)
    AC_CONFIG_FILES(foo.conf)

    AC_PROG_CC
    AC_PROG_INSTALL
    AC_PROG_MAKE_SET
    AC_PROG_MKDIR_P

    AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
    AC_OUTPUT
```

foo.conf.in:

```
    Dir = @datadir@/@PACKAGE@
```

The resulting foo.conf:

```
    Dir = ${prefix}/share/foo
```

I would like autoconf to evaluate the `${prefix}` when substituting, and I don't know how to make that happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't substitute Makefile variables like `datadir` at configure-time, since they aren't fully expanded. (See the documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Scripts.html).)

The unfortunate solution if you want to do both configure-time and build-time substitutions is to do a two-step substitution, from `foo.conf.in.in` to `foo.conf.in` at configure time, and `foo.conf.in` to `foo.conf` at build time:

in configure.ac:

```
AC_SUBST([PACKAGE])
AC_PROG_SED
AC_CONFIG_FILES([foo.conf.in])
```

in Makefile.am:

```
edit_script = $(SED) \
    -e 's,%datadir%,$(datadir),'g \
    -e ...other build-time substitutions you might want to do... \
    $(NULL)
foo.conf: foo.conf.in Makefile
    $(AM_V_GEN)rm -f $@ $@.tmp && \
    $(edit_script) $< >$@.tmp && \
    chmod a-w $@.tmp && \
    mv $@.tmp $@
CLEANFILES += foo.conf
```

in foo.conf.in.in:

```
 Dir = %datadir%/@PACKAGE@
```

I happen to use `%` signs for build-time substitutions so that I don't confuse them with configure-time substitutions marked by `@`. The makefile rule above also makes the generated `foo.conf` readonly so that you don't edit it by mistake and get your changes overwritten.

Comment: It looks like that is the way to go. Thanks for the clever response.

Answer (score 1):

A second parameter can be added to  `AC_CONFIG_FILES` which is shell code to run in the context of the variables inside the *configure* script.

So you can add some sort of substitution there. For example change

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES(foo.conf)
```

to:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([foo.conf], [sed -i -e"s/\${prefix}/$prefix/" foo.conf])
```

What I do if this code gets long and unwieldy to put it all in a separate file and run that, or perhaps *source* it.

*Disclaimer:* When I tried to replicate your results, I was getting messages about `--dataroot` getting ignored and *$prefix* didn't appear in `foo.conf` 2nd disclaimer. I am not a fan of autoconf.

Comment: This won't work because `$prefix` is not defined in shell during execution of `commands` argument of `AC_CONFIG_FILES`. You need to add third argument (`init-cmds`). Besides, if `$prefix` contains slashes, and it usually does, then your `sed` call will fail. You need to replace slashes with something else, e.g. a percent sign: `AC_CONFIG_FILES([foo.conf], [sed -i -e "s%\${prefix}%$prefix%/g" foo.conf], [export prefix=$prefix])`

See https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Actions.html